# 403 Forbidden and "no release file" errors when I try to add a PPA for Lutris

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, ppa, lutris

```
yarob@yarob-2184:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris
 Stable releases for the Lutris client
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~lutris-team/+archive/ubuntu/lutris
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://deb.playonlinux.com cosmic InRelease
Get:2 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,441 B]
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chrdevs/figma/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu focal InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/ppa-kicad/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python PPA from JonathonF is discontinued, so you have to remove it from the system and update packages lists by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6

sudo apt-get update
```

About postgresql repository you have to check the CPU architecture of the installed system and maybe change related source.list line by changing its first characters from `deb` to `deb [arch=amd64]`  and then update package lists again.